# How do I enable custom headers with CORS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am attempting to set up CORS on my C# Web API following Microsoft's guide which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors). Here are the steps I followed.

1. Install CORS.

[image: Cors is installed]

2. Enable CORS in the WebApiConfig class.

[image: Cors Enabled]

3. Enable CORS within the Controller for the given endpoint.

[image: CORS on Controller]

Now it should be noted that this endpoint does require a custom header. My current understanding is that when I use the EnableCors attribute and use a wildcard "*" for the headers, then all headers are allowed. However, when I attempt to call this endpoint I'm met with the following error in Chrome dev tools.

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi/getdata/myid' from origin 'http://localhost:12345' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field myheaderfield is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

I've tried changing the allowed headers from wildcard "*" to "myheaderfield" but the error remains the same. How do I enable custom headers with CORS?

Below is the JS XHR request I am using to make this call.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://myapi/getdata/myid");
xhr.setRequestHeader("myheaderfield", "abc123");

xhr.send();
```

Comment: For .Net 5/ASP.Net Core, try abdulraheem alarpi's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589429/421195) below.  For customer headers with CORS in general, look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: I think you can try https://myapi/getdata/?id=myid when making JS call

Answer (score 2):

just Allow-Headers to access In asp.net core

In ConfigureServices like that:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("name of cors", builder => 
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Comment: Is this only available in .Net 5/ASP.Net Core? I'm on .Net 4.7.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net 4.7.2 To allow any headers, set headers to "*". To allow specific headers, set headers to a comma-separated list of the allowed headers Like That:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", 
    headers: "accept,content-type,origin,x-my-header", methods: "*")]
```

And This Link Explaine Full Cors In .Net FrameWork

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.7, if you want to add custom header globally, then do like the following on your Register method:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // ...
    }
```

If you want as per controller, then add `config.EnableCors(cors);` on your Register method and on your controller do like below:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", 
    headers: "accept,content-type,origin,x-my-header", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: If you are on .NET 4.7.2, then this will work. Please let me know and don't forget to mark as answer.